# MySQL move comma separated values from one column into another

Tags: mysql

Good Evening Everyone;

I have a table in MySql that I would like to update as follows. Just as an FYI I have searched this topic and have yet to find a solution.

The table name is `ALK_Results_NEW` in a MySQl database, the data in the `ICD9` column contains data seperated by commas. 
I need to keep the first set in the `ICD9` column so for example the first row has V57.9 , 246.9. 
I need to keep the V57.9 in the `ICD9` column and move 246.9 into the `ICD9_SECONDARY` column. 
If a row has more than 2 then I need to move all other into the `ICD9_OTHER` column (This column can have mulitple `ICD9` Codes separated by commas)

To summarize the first code needs to stay in the `ICD9` column and the second set of codes needs to be moved into the `ICD9_SECONDARY`. After the data is moved the `ICD9` Column should only have the forst set of codes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two columns already exist in the table, you can change the data using an `update`:

```
update alk_results_new
    set icd9_secondary = substr(icd9, instr(icd9, ',') + 1),
        icd9 = substring_index(icd9, ',', 1)
    where icd9 like '%,%';
```

EDIT:

Oops, I didn't realize there were three columns.  The approach is similar, but a little more complicated because you need to take into account the length of the strings.  I think the following should do what you want:

```
update alk_results_new
    set icd9_other = (case when icd9 like '%,%,%'
                           then substr(icd9, length(substring_index(icd9, ',', 2)) + 2)
                      end),
        icd9_secondary = (case when icd9 like '%,%'
                               then substring_index(substring_index(icd9, ',', 2), ',', -1) 
                          end),
        icd9 = substring_index(icd9, ',', 1);
```

Note:  test the logic out on a `select` before running the `update`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, just one quick question, I see where you SET icd9_secondary, and icd9 but no mention of the ICD9_OTHER. I need to keep the first set in the ICD9 column so for example the first row has V57.9 , 246.9. I need to keep the V57.9 in the ICD9 column and move 246.9 into the ICD9_SECONDARY column. If a row has more than 2 then I need to move all other into the ICD9_OTHER column (This column can have mulitple ICD9 Codes separated by commas)

Comment: By the way I purchased your book a few months back and it rocks!!! really helped take my excel skills to another level

Comment: Hey there I am getting this error when using the select statement, any suggestions? 


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET ICD9_Other = (case when icd9 like '%,%,%'
                           then SU' at line 2

Comment: Also getting this error in MySQL 2010

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.

Comment: @FrankRivera . . . There is no `charindex()` in my code.

Comment: @FrankRivera:- You can accept the answer if that helped you. (A right tick mark turns green when clicked!)